# Decomposition of character into irreducible character imply decomposition of representation into irreducible representations.

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Let G be a group and $H\le G$ be a subgroup. Let $W$ be a representation of H for which the associated character is $\eta$ and suppose moreover that $\{\chi_1,\ldots,\chi_r\}$ are the irreducible characters of $G$ for which the respective representations are $V_1,\ldots,V_r$.

Now $\operatorname{Ind}^G_HW$ is a representation of G for which we will denote the character $\chi$. Using Frobenius reciprocity, I can often express $\operatorname{Ind}^G_H\eta=\sum\limits_{k=1}^r a_k \chi_k$ but then it is not clear why $\operatorname{Ind}^G_HW=\bigoplus_{k=1}^r V_k$ (or maybe it is another direct sum, I am not sure).

Comment: Yes, thank you for spotting the typo, I edited

Comment: Since you are talking about Frobenius reciprocity, I assume the field here is $\mathbb{C}$. So are you really asking why the character determines the representation?

Comment: I actually understand that if $V, W$ are representations with respective characters $\chi, \eta$ then $\chi=\eta \iff V \cong W$. It is just putting the pieces together I don't get

Comment: I'm trying to understand what actually you want to know. Frobenius reciprocity doesn't tell you how to find the submodules explicitly, it just says that they are there.

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is. "if $\chi_1,\ldots,\chi_r$ are characters of $V_1, \ldots ,V_r$ then why is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^r a_k \chi_k$ a character of $V_1\oplus \ldots \oplus V_r$"?

Comment: It isn't. It's the character of $V_1^{\oplus a_1}\oplus \cdots \oplus V_r^{\oplus a_r}$.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I ment that

Comment: The trace of a block-diagonal sum of matrices is the sum of the traces?

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks for enlightening those points for me